# 1.9.3.8 Multistore loading wrong website code

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-website

I have a 1.9.3.8 multistore set up at a temporary domain, with several websites set up within the multistore.  These websites broken up by brick and mortar location, for what it's worth.

The homepage of the default website is a typical homepage with a banner and whatnot.  But the homepage for any location is the root category with layered navigation (using amasty's plugin for this.  We are also using cart2quote, but I doubt that's causing the issue.  In any case, I have disabled these plugins temporarily, and the problem I'm having remains.)

The problem is that when I load one of the locations, the homepage is the original default home page!  I did some digging into that:  The `$mageRunCode` and `$mageRunType` are both being set properly in the `index.php` file.  However, when I check `Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getName()`, the value is the default website!  This means that all my config values are pointing to the wrong scope!  Why would this happen?!  I'm flabbergasted.  Anyone ever experienced this?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

1. For the multiple website config, Add the code bellow in your `index.php` right before `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

   ```
   switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
       case 'domain1.com':
       case 'www.domain1.com':
           $mageRunCode = 'domain1_com';
           $mageRunType = 'website';
       break;
       case 'domain2.com':
       case 'www.domain2.com':
           $mageRunCode = 'domain2_com';
           $mageRunType = 'website';
       break;
   }
   ```

   Don't forget to point your domaine urls in your Vhost.
2. For the homepage, you can can config the homepage per website in : `System > Configuration > General > Web > Default Page.`
3. Clean the cache.

Comment: I have done this already and the same issue is happening.  The `$mageRunCode` and `$mageRunType` are correct, however the actual loaded website remains default.  I know this because in step 2, I have the default page settings set to the category page, and when I check that config value, it still shows the default settings.  I have cache turned off, however, I clear it every time.